# Where is the file stored to be read by FileInputStream?

Tags: java, file-handling

I'm getting 'File not found!' no matter what I do.

```
FileInputStream fin;
    try {
        fin = new FileInputStream("foo.txt");
        String str = IOUtils.toString(fin);
        System.out.println(str);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a foo.txt in the directory that you are working in?.

If you are using command window and are at a location say, C:\, then your code expects foo.txt to be present there.

If your foo.txt is present in some other path, use the full path in your code.

Comment: It is present in the directory. Still there's error.

Comment: EDIT: Works after giving the full path but not else wise. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Curious, are you using any IDE or are you using java from command line.

Comment: I'am using netbeans as an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

If you temporarily add this line to your code:

```
System.out.println(new File("foo.txt").getAbsolutePath());
```

it should tell you where it expects to find the file. If the file isn't in that location, then you'll either have to specify the path or move the file so that it is.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the correct path. Try right-clicking and go on to Properties and check the file's path. Copy and paste the path and replace all the `\` to either `/` or `\\`.

Comment: Works after giving the full path but not else wise. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it works, could you accept either mine or Pavan's answer? It's always good to accept answers that actually helped your problem.